# Google Maps: add to contacts

Tags: google-contacts, google-maps

I've searched Google Maps for a business.  I've found it.  I'm looking at the popup/bubble/whatever on the map, for that business.

Is there something I can from this point to quickly get that business added to my Google Contacts?

Comment: Only way I can see at the moment is to send yourself an email, then import the contact details from the email?

Comment: That's a shame. Golden opportunity here, Google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked and you can on the latest version of Maps on Android. If I wanted to save the contact to my contacts I would use "Chrome to Phone" to get the map on my phone, tap on the location to get the details page for that location and scroll down to "Add as a Contact".

Update for April 2020: In the Android Google Maps app, select the business, then click on **the three dots menu** on the top right.

An "Add to Contacts" entry is there. Unfortunately, it seems not to import all the infos from the Maps page, just the address.

Comment: Sadly this is not possible anymore because they removed the add to contacts from maps in the newest version. Or I can't find it anymoare.

Comment: @Janusz Not surprised . . . in the age of constant updates and "ALL NEW" it seems that losing some feature you like is the norm.

Comment: @tooshel that applies more to free apps and less to paid/SAAS based apps

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple other ways. You can "Star" it in Google maps on your PC. "Star" icon is directly under the little RED bubble balloon thing on the far left side of the local listing. Once you star it, it saves that to "My Places"(as long as you are signed into a gmail acct) Using your phone now Open Google Maps, and look at the map and find the star. You will be able to touch on it to pull up that listing. Then hit the settings button and then touch "Add As a Contact" or another way is to Just click the Local tab on www.google.com to see starred items and quickly find hours, reviews, and phone numbers.  This is still not as efficient as a simple "ADD to contacts" feature from maps on the PC.  Unless i missed something.  Please post if you know a quicker way.

Comment: I can find only one way?

Answer (score 1):

On Android (as of Oct 2019):

1. Open the *Phone* app
2. Search for a listing you want to add
3. Results include both your contacts and *Google Search listings*
4. Touch the icon to the left of the *listing* you want to add
5. The listing will open and display **Add to contacts** button
6. Touch **Add to contacts** and then add it as a *New contact*
7. Edit as desired, and Save the new contact.

[image]

Comment: At least in Android 8.1.0, when I *Search* in the *Phone* app, I cannot see results from web searches, but only in my contacts. And I found no setting enabling for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do. It is not a direct add, but better than tedious copy paste.

Copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> each item one by one using a clipboard manager (e.g.: [ClipDiary](http://clipdiary.com/screenshots.php) —I already have it installed). I don't lose an already copied item when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+C next time—ClipDiary remembers it. Now open up Gmail contacts and paste one after another and save the contact.

Answer (score 0):

Update for April 2020: 
In the Android Google Maps app, select the business, then click on the three dots menu on the top right.

An "Add to Contacts" entry is there. Unfortunately, it seems not to import all the infos from the Maps page, just the address.

Answer (score -1):

once i found the place on the map i then copy the name and go to the pone and search my contacts for the name. Google will then use google to search by name when its not in your phone book. from there you can add the contact. still should be something you can do from the map. Fail at google.